# What is the relation between arguments used in YAML and class arguments in the yolov5 implementation by ultralytics?

Tags: python, deep-learning, yaml, yolo, yolov5

I was working on fish detection and tracking system in 3 dimensions using MS Kinect, and used yolov5s for rgb frames. I wanted to experiment a bit with the architecture
of yolov5, but as a beginner i am struggling to find the relation between the arguments in the classes used in common.py and the arguments used in yaml
file in the ultralytics repo. Can anybody help ?
PS : If you can add in some resources from where i can learn about the architecture and layers, then it would really help. Thank you !

Comment: Can you provide an example of the yaml file and the class arguments and explain what you don't understand more specifically?

Comment: @KyleL
yaml : https://github.com/sanyamss99/yolov5/blob/master/models/yolov5.yaml
classes : https://github.com/sanyamss99/yolov5/blob/master/models/common.py
I have added the C3TR layers with arguments , but they are not compatible. I am not able to understand how to decide the arguments based on class arguments and previous layer and other factors if any. Please help.